# MSM - new site displays wrong templates

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have 5 sites including the default site. Sites 1-4 are fine, but my fifth site is displaying templates from site no. 4. I have copied the admin.php and index.php from the default site and updated them where necessary. I have created new templates in site no. 5 but they are being ignored. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply recreating the site didn't fix it.
Creating a differently named site, then recreating the problem site as the 6th site fixed it.